# retaining $PATH between processes in cloudbees jenkins

Tags: path, jenkins, cloudbees

Jenkins on Cloudbees - 
I have 2 shell scripts:

1 - Sets `$PATH` to include

> /scratch/jenkins/addons/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p247-x86_64/bin

2 - echos `$PATH`

```
From script 1:  + /scratch/jenkins/addons/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p247-x86_64/bin:/scratch/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodeJS_Install/bin:/opt/jdk/latest/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/maven/latest/bin:/opt/ant/latest/bin:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/gradle/latest/bin:/home/jenkins/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk.latest/bin
+ sh/echo_path.sh
From script 2:  + /scratch/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodeJS_Install/bin:/opt/jdk/latest/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/maven/latest/bin:/opt/ant/latest/bin:/opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/gradle/latest/bin:/home/jenkins/bin:/opt/jdk/jdk.latest/bin
```

As you can see script 2 has lost the ruby entry made by script 1 to `$PATH`. Why does this happen and can it be stopped as it affects the build steps further down the line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EnvInject plugin for the originally requested purpose. From [its wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin#EnvInjectPlugin-Someusecases):

> To inject variables as a build step obtained from a file filled in by a previous build step

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is use the envinject plugin to set that environment variable for the entire build. Shell script build steps are just regular shell scripts. They can't export environment variables to their parent process.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that i'm installing ruby & compass from the shell script as they need to be used in a gradle build further down the chain so the envinject plugin wouldn't help as ruby is setup each & every time in cloudbees.

Comment: I realize that Ruby & compass are being installed by the shell script, but since you know their paths ahead of time, I don't see why you can't add them to the $PATH.

Comment: @thanks for your input but absolute ref is an option I was looking to avoid (either via your method of in the down stream scripts) because if cloudbees were to change anything going forward the it breaks the build process - more wanting to get to the bottom as to why this happen..